# Listener for clipboard content change?

Tags: android, clipboard, clipboard-interaction

Is there a way to register a method so that it's automatically called as soon as the user ends "text selection mode" (thereby copying selection to clipboard)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#addPrimaryClipChangedListener%28android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener%29).

**Edit** - this is for Android 3.0, and I don't see any other clipboard-related apis in the earlier levels.

Also see the [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html#ClipboardManager) docs in the copy and paste guide.

Comment: I think you're right. :)  Unfortunately, it's only available from API level 11. I need something that would work at least on Android 2.2 (API level 8). http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#level11 Nevertheless, your answer is the correct one and so I am going to accept it, although I would love to see other suggestions that somehow work on API level 8 (polling?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android 3.0 you can add a listener with [ClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#addPrimaryClipChangedListener%28android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener%29).

Comment: It triggers the callback even if same text is copied again and again. Can you listen only when copied text is different than before?

Answer (score 2):

I need the exact same functionality. For the moment I'm solving this with `android.text.ClipboardManager` and a java `Timer` that checks every second if the clipboard-text has changed.

Comment: can you give few inputs on how you did this with a Timer ?