# How to detect a "copy to clipboard" event

Tags: android, copy, clipboard

I would like to detect the event of "copy to clipboard", so when a user, after having selected a string or url, tap on `copy to clipboard`.

Do you have any idea how to check this in an Android environment?

Comment: For Android: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931359/how-to-listen-for-a-copy-in-android

Comment: There is a tutorial on Google code - https://code.google.com/archive/p/my-clips/ Check out, you will like it. It's for clipboard

Comment: Thank you guys, I am gonna make this question just for Android. For a java application for computer I could create a new question.

Comment: Does it mean that we now can't copy a link to clipboard without being tracked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html

```
ClipboardManager
.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
  @Override
  protected void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
    Log.i("clipboard", "changed to:" + ClipboardManager.getText());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener` and `ClipboardManager.getText()` are deprecated. New solution:

```
val clipboardManager = context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener {
    val clipboardAsText = clipboardManager.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text
    if (clipboardAsText != null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Text in clipboard: $clipboardAsText", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```