# private clipboard in android

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it feasible to implement a sandboxed clipboard in my Android app, preventing copied content within my app from being pasted into other apps? Are there any strategies or APIs to achieve this without overriding the system context menu?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit "hacky" but one way you could achieve this is by using [the Clipboard manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager) and using it in `onStop` of your activity to clear the clipboard data (but that would erase the data, even if the user returned to the app, so you could also read the clipboard and save it locally and re-save it when the user returns to the app)

the problem with this approach is: it will always (even if the user didn't copy) remove clipboard data

Comment: but you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162641/how-to-detect-a-copy-to-clipboard-event) to listen for copy-events and check whether the user has copied anything and if so, clear the clipboard (but I hope there is a better approach)

Answer (score 0):

can override the system context action easily without affecting all the text inputs,
by setting custom ActionMode for edit text, we could change the action of copy ,paste and other context actions of edit text

Created a Singleton to hold the clipboard content(can use sharedPrefs or others)

```
object CustomClipboard {
    private var text = ""
    fun copy(text: String) {
        if(text.isNotEmpty())
            this.text = text
    }
    fun paste() = text
}
```

created a CustomEditText

```
class CustomEditText( context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : AppCompatEditText(context) {
    private val actionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        //todo: explore all the methods
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            //see if data is copied or cut
            return if (item?.isClipboardAction() == true) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "custom action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                when (item.itemId) {
                    android.R.id.copy -> {
                        CustomClipboard.copy(this@CustomEditText.getSelectedText())
                    }

                    android.R.id.cut -> {
                        CustomClipboard.copy(this@CustomEditText.getSelectedText())
                        this@CustomEditText.text?.delete(
                            this@CustomEditText.selectionStart,
                            this@CustomEditText.selectionEnd
                        )
                    }

                    android.R.id.paste, android.R.id.pasteAsPlainText -> {
                        if (this@CustomEditText.getSelectedText().isEmpty()) {
                            this@CustomEditText.text?.insert(
                                this@CustomEditText.selectionStart,
                                CustomClipboard.paste()
                            )
                        } else {
                            this@CustomEditText.text?.replace(
                                this@CustomEditText.selectionStart,
                                this@CustomEditText.selectionEnd,
                                CustomClipboard.paste()
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                mode?.finish()
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {

        }
    }

    init {
        customInsertionActionModeCallback = actionModeCallback
        customSelectionActionModeCallback = actionModeCallback
    }

}
fun MenuItem.isClipboardAction(): Boolean {
    return itemId == android.R.id.copy || itemId == android.R.id.cut || itemId == android.R.id.paste || itemId == android.R.id.pasteAsPlainText
}
fun EditText.getSelectedText(): String {
    val start = selectionStart
    val end = selectionEnd
    if (start != end) {
        return text.substring(start, end)
    }
    return ""
}
```

now we can use it in Layout Like

```
<com.tao.myapp.CustomEditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

the problem with this approach is the content copied from outside the app will not available to paste inside the app

i tried listening clipboard change and storing it in the CustomClipboard of my app using a background thread,
the callback is not always working